# landing page issue in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-frontend

I try to build a landing page using bootstrap.
I created a section with icon and

tags.
but the text in p and h3 tags look like this

[image]

here is code for section:

```
 <section id="process" class="process">
            <div class="container-fluid container-fluid-max">
                <div class="row text-center py-5 ">
                  <div class="col-12 pb-4">
                    <h2 class="text-red">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 pl-12 pr-12 ml-13 mr-13">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                            <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                        </span>
                        <h3 class="mt-3 text-red h4">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                            <i class="fas fa-school"></i>
                        </span>
                        <h3 class="mt-3 text-red h4">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                       <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                            <i class="fas fa-school"></i>
                        </span>
                        <h3 class="mt-3 text-red h4">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                            <i class="fas fa-school"></i>
                        </span>
                        <h3 class="mt-3 text-red h4">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </section>
```

i want to mage text be in one or 2 lines.

Comment: Practice not to add ".col*" inside ".col*" without using ".row"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct you code, you have doubles of blocks width `class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3"`, do like this

```
<section id="process" class="process">
           <div class="container-fluid container-fluid-max">
               <div class="row text-center py-5 ">
                 <div class="col-12 pb-4">
                   <h2 class="text-red">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                       <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                           <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                       </span>
                       <h3 class="mt-3 text-red h4">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                       <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                           <i class="fas fa-school"></i>
                       </span>
                       <h3 class="mt-3 text-red h4">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                       <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                           <i class="fas fa-school"></i>
                       </span>
                       <h3 class="mt-3 text-red h4">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                 </div>
                       <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                           <i class="fas fa-school"></i>
                       </span>
                       <h3 class="mt-3 text-red h4">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
       </section>
```

Comment: i added .mw-100 class to second div and fixed the problem.

Comment: But this is incorrect to use `col` inside a `col`. easier to remove unnecessary classes then add some new to fix them

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have declared columns inside columns.

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      ----                     
    </div>
 </div>
```

In the above code, 2nd div will be taking 3 columns space of 1st div in large screens(col-lg-3) and 6 columns space in small screens(col-sm-6). It won't take complete column width of 1st div

[image]